# Why I cant run local fonts in my tailwind/react js project?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, local, google-fonts

Here is the main CSS file of Tailwind:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

#__next {
  min-height: 100%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'notosans';
  src: local('notosans-semibold2'), local('notosans-semibold'),
    url('@/assets/fonts/notosans-semibold2.woff2');
  font-weight: 600;
}`
```

The code in `tailwind.config.js` file

```
fontFamily: {
    sans: ['Inter', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
    display: ['Lexend', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
    notosans: ['notosans'],
},
```

And this is the relative path where the font is located:

```
src/assets/fonts/notosans-semibold2.woff2
```

The font I am trying to import locally is the `notosans-semibold2.woff2` which is downloaded from Google Fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `@` from `url('@/assets/...')`

Given your code, it seems that the files are located in a static directory. Therefore, you can directly reference them.

Comment: How can i directly reference them ( i want them global in every page)

Comment: @XIz in your case, it should be `url('/assets/...')`

Comment: still not working